# shell program that support IO redirection

Tags: c++, shell, fork, pipe

This is an assignment create a shell in C++.

I type in `ls | sort` it works perfect. But when I type in one more command (`ls | sort | head`), it can not run and show this error:

```
error: Resource temporarily unavailable
makefile:8: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Here is the code

```
void rePipe(pid_t pid[], vector<Command> cmds, int count)
{
    if(count == cmds.size())
    {
        return;
    }

    pid[count] = fork();

    if (pid[count] < 0)
    {
        perror( "error" );
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid[count] == 0)  //child
    {
        if(cmds[count].input)
        {
            int fin = open(cmds[count].inputfile, O_RDONLY, 0666);
            dup2(fin, 0);
            close(fin);
        }
        if(cmds[count].output)
        {
            int fout = open(cmds[count].outputfile, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);
            dup2(fout, 1);
            close(fout);
        }

        if(count == (cmds.size() -1) )
        {
            close(cmds[count-1].pipeNum[1]);
            dup2(cmds[count-1].pipeNum[0], 0);
        }
        else
        {
            close(cmds[count-1].pipeNum[1]);

            dup2(cmds[count-1].pipeNum[0], 0);

            dup2(cmds[count].pipeNum[1], 1);
            close(cmds[count].pipeNum[1]);
        }

        execvp (cmds[count].cmd[0], cmds[count].cmd);
        perror("Can't execute" );
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        if(count < (cmds.size() -1))
            rePipe(pid, cmds, count++);

        wait(NULL);
    }


}

void execute(vector<Command> cmds)
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < cmds.size(); ++i)
        pipe(cmds[i].pipeNum);

    pid_t pid[cmds.size()];


    pid[count] = fork();

    if (pid[count] < 0)
    {
        perror( "error" );
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid[count] == 0)  //child
    {
        if(cmds[count].input)
        {
            int fin = open(cmds[count].inputfile, O_RDONLY, 0666);
            dup2(fin, 0);
            close(fin);
        }
        if(cmds[count].output)
        {
            int fout = open(cmds[count].outputfile, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);
            dup2(fout, 1);
            close(fout);
        }
        if(cmds.size() > 1)
        {
            close(cmds[count].pipeNum[0]);
            dup2(cmds[count].pipeNum[1], 1);
            close(cmds[count].pipeNum[1]);

        }

        execvp (cmds[count].cmd[0], cmds[count].cmd);
        perror("Can't execute" );
        exit(1);
    }
    else //parent
    {
        if(cmds.size() > 1)
        {
            rePipe(pid, cmds, 1);
        }

        for(auto & cmd: cmds)
        {   
            close(cmd.pipeNum[0]);
            close(cmd.pipeNum[1]);
        }

        if ( waitpid( pid[cmds.size() - 1], 0, 0 ) < 0 )
        {
            perror( "Internal error: cannot wait for child." );

            exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what does `make` have to do with this?

Comment: You mean the error message?
I don't know what is that.

Comment: Your error message suggests you're running this through `make`. Why? What I'm getting at is that you need to figure out where that `Resource temporarily unavailable` error message is coming from. That means take out as much complexity as possible, then start narrowing your code to the bare essentials. You're not getting much attention here because you just pasted a wall of code and expect us to debug it for you, when you haven't even fully described what the code does or is supposed to do.